# "Waking up" selenium node or stopping it from going down?

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium node running on a docker container that is used by a webscraping application that should run once every day. The section in my docker-compose-file that defines the docker container running selenium looks like this:

```
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My first idea was that I let this docker container stay up at all times so that my webscraping application can use it when it needs it. But I realized that the selenium node goes down after a while. This causes my webscraping application to fail unless I restart the docker container.

```
14:59:20.917 INFO [GridModel.release] - Releasing slot for session id 2886674dc691af220420ae7eee51be34
14:59:20.917 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session 2886674dc691af220420ae7eee51be34
17:12:06.151 INFO [GridModel.purgeDeadNodes] - Switching Node http://172.19.0.4:4444 from UP to DOWN
17:12:36.151 INFO [GridModel.purgeDeadNodes] - Removing Node http://172.19.0.4:4444, DOWN for too long
18:27:00.906 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "506b3e29aaa45e31245d6c6d8cf80c32","eventTime": 1681064820905344362,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "192.168.1.239:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "435","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f3.141.0 (python linux)"}}
18:38:13.503 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "709e8ef4aac83442ed23598781f89d2a","eventTime": 1681065493501962460,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "192.168.1.239:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "435","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f3.141.0 (python linux)"}}
18:47:48.032 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$3] - {"traceId": "b56c80b83d065cb63713f387a261cf41","eventTime": 1681066068031056753,"eventName": "HTTP request execution complete","attributes": {"http.flavor": 1,"http.handler_class": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue","http.host": "192.168.1.239:4444","http.method": "POST","http.request_content_length": "435","http.scheme": "HTTP","http.status_code": 500,"http.target": "\u002fsession","http.user_agent": "selenium\u002f3.141.0 (python linux)"}}
```

Is there something I can do to wake up the node again before the webscraping application is run? Or even better stop the node from going down in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that covers my needs. It's not doing exactly what I asked for but It's a decent work around.

Instead of using the available selenium docker image and reference that docker container when creating the webdriver in the webscraper script, I just created a custom docker image that hosts selenium and the webscraper application.

This is the Dockerfile for that docker image.

```
# Use Alpine as the base image
FROM alpine:latest

# Install necessary packages
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
    wget \
    unzip \
    xvfb \
    curl \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver

# Install Selenium
RUN pip3 install selenium==4.4.3 webdriver_manager
RUN pip3 install kafka-python==2.0.2

# Set up Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer)
RUN Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

# Set the environment variables
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"

# Copy application file to the container
COPY src/docker/webscraper/webscraper_app.py root/app.py
COPY build/.env ./.env

# Set up cronjob
COPY src/docker/webscraper/cronjobs /etc/crontabs/root
CMD ["crond","-f", "-d", "1", "-L", "/dev/stdout"]
```

the `cronjoobs`-file is a file that defines the schedule on which the webscraping application should run. So the docker container is always up and running and Selenium never goes down.